# How to setup Push/Pull in Git?

Tags: git, config

How to do Push / Pull works automatically with the other branch of remote repository?
By default, created a "master".
I added "develop".
I want everyone to have worked with develop. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created a branch named "develop" on the remote repository, everyone that clones this repository will have a reference to this branch, e.g. "origin/develop", if the alias for the remote repository is "origin".

So if I cloned this repository and wanted to work against the develop branch on the remote repository, I'd create a local branch named "develop" that's tracking "origin/develop". This can be done in various ways and with different syntax, but I prefer:

> git checkout --track origin/develop

I can now edit and commit files to my local develop branch and do "git pull" and "git push" to sync with the remote branch.

If you already have a local branch named develop, which is not a tracking branch, you can set it up with the following command:

> git branch --set-upstream develop
>   origin/develop

Hope this helps!